# Sum Product GUI Repeat

Tags: swing, user-interface, jframe

Okay so I have to "Design and implement an application that uses dialog boxes to obtain tow integer values (one dialog box for each value), and display the sum and product of the values. Use another dialog box to prompt whether the user wants to process another pair of values." So far I have this:

```
public class SumProductPanel extends JPanel {   
String number1;
String number2;
static JFrame frame;

public SumProductPanel(){

    number1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( "Please enter the first integer      value" );
    number2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( "Please enter the first integer value" );

    int int1 = Integer.parseInt(number1);
    int int2 = Integer.parseInt(number2);

    SortedSet<Integer> set = new TreeSet<>();
    set.add(int1);
    set.add(int2);

    int sum = int1 + int2;
    int product = int1 * int2;
    JLabel label = new JLabel();
    label.setText("The sum of the two intergers is:");
    JLabel labelsum = new JLabel();
    labelsum.setText(String.valueOf(sum));
    JLabel label2 = new JLabel();
    label2.setText("The product of the two intergers is:");
    JLabel labelproduct = new JLabel();
    labelproduct.setText(String.valueOf(product));
    add(label);
    add(labelsum);
    add(label2);
    add(labelproduct);
    }





}
```

and I also have this

```
public class SumProduct {


public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setTitle("Sum Product");
    frame.setSize(300, 100);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JPanel panel = new SumProductPanel();
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
    frame.setVisible(true);

}
}
```

My problem is that I have no idea how to do the part "Use another dialog box to prompt whether the user wants to process another pair of values." If anyone could help me that would be great.